# Convert pygame to exe

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.3, py2exe, cx-freeze

When i try to convert this to a .exe file with py2exe it says "Import error, no module named pygame". How can i convert it to a .exe usin py2exe? If anyone can help me convert it with another tool, please let me know.

```
import pygame
import spritesheet
import os.path
import math
import random
from pygame.locals import *
from SpriteStripAnim import SpriteStripAnim

# Variaveis para a interface com o utilizador
Largura = 800
Altura = 600
pontos = 0
vidas = 5
tempo = 0.5
iniciado = False

#==============================================================================#
#                  Classe para trabalhar com imagens                           #
#==============================================================================#
class ImageInfo:
    def __init__(self, center, size, radius=0, lifespan=None, animated=False):
        self.center = center
        self.size = size
        self.radius = radius
        self.lifespan = lifespan if lifespan else float('inf')
        self.animated = animated

    def get_center(self):
        return self.center

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def get_lifespan(self):
        return self.lifespan

    def get_animated(self):
        return self.animated


# Definir o caminho actual
main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]

# Funcao auxiliar para o carregamento de imagens
def carregar_imagem(file):
    "carregar uma imagem, e prepara-la para o jogo"
    file = os.path.join(main_dir, 'art', file)
    try:
        surface = pygame.image.load(file)
    except pygame.error:
        raise SystemExit('Nao foi possivel carregar a imagem "%s" %s' % (file, pygame.get_error()))
    return surface.convert_alpha()

# Funcao auxiliar para o carregamento de sons
def carregar_som(file):
    file = os.path.join(main_dir, 'audio', file)
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file)
    return sound


# Funcoes auxiliares para lidar com as tranformacoes
def angle_to_vector(ang):
    return [math.cos(ang), math.sin(ang)] 

def dist(p, q):
    return math.sqrt((p[0] - q[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - q[1]) ** 2)  

def rot_center(image, angle):
    """Rodar uma imagem enquanto conserva o centro e o tamanho da imagem"""
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image


#==============================================================================#
#                              Classe Nave                                     #
#==============================================================================#
class Nave:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, angle, image, info):
        self.pos = [pos[0], pos[1]]
        self.vel = [vel[0], vel[1]]
        self.thrust = False
        self.angle = angle
        self.angle_vel = 0
        self.images = image
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.image_width = self.image.get_width()
        self.image_height = self.image.get_height()
        self.original = self.image
        self.image_center = info.get_center()
        self.image_size = info.get_size()
        self.radius = info.get_radius()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.center_pos = [(self.pos[0] + self.image_width / 2), (self.pos[1] + self.image_height / 2)]

    def get_position(self):
        return self.pos

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def turn(self, direction):
        self.angle_vel = direction

    def move(self, thrust):
        self.thrust = thrust
        if self.thrust:
            ship_thrust_sound.play(-1)
        else:
            ship_thrust_sound.stop()

    def shoot(self):
        global missile_group
        base_missle_speed = 6
        frente = angle_to_vector(math.radians(self.angle))
        vel = [0, 0]
        vel[0] = self.vel[0] + frente[0] * base_missle_speed
        vel[1] = self.vel[1] + -frente[1] * base_missle_speed

        pos = [0, 0]
        pos[0] = self.pos[0] + (self.radius + 5 + self.image_width / 2 * frente[0])
        pos[1] = self.pos[1] + (self.radius + 5 + self.image_height / 2 * -frente[1])

        a_missile = Sprite(pos, vel, 0, 0, missile_image, missile_info, missile_sound)
        missile_group.add(a_missile)

    def draw(self, tela):
        if self.thrust:
            self.original = self.images[1]
        else:
            self.original = self.images[0]

        tela.blit(self.image, self.pos)

    def update(self):
        #Actualizar posicao
        self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]
        self.center_pos = [(self.pos[0] + self.image_width / 2), (self.pos[1] + self.image_height / 2)]

        # Actualizacao do atrito
        c = 0.015
        self.vel[0] *= (1 - c)
        self.vel[1] *= (1 - c)

        # Envolvimento do ecra
        if self.pos[1] + self.image_height <= self.radius:  
            self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] % Altura + self.image_height
        if self.pos[1] >= Altura:
            self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] % Altura - self.image_height

        if self.pos[0] + self.image_width <= 0:  
            self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] % Largura + self.image_width
        if self.pos[0] >= Largura:
            self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] % Largura - self.image_width

        # Acelerando para a frente
        frente = angle_to_vector(math.radians(self.angle))
        if self.thrust:
            self.vel[0] += frente[0] * 0.1
            self.vel[1] += -frente[1] * 0.1
        self.angle += self.angle_vel
        self.image = rot_center(self.original, self.angle)

#==============================================================================#
#                              Classe Sprite                                   #
#==============================================================================#
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, ang, ang_vel, image, info, sound=None, strip=None):
        self.pos = [pos[0], pos[1]]
        self.vel = [vel[0], vel[1]]
        self.angle = ang
        self.angle_vel = ang_vel
        self.image = image
        self.original = self.image
        self.image_width = self.image.get_width()
        self.image_height = self.image.get_height()
        self.image_center = info.get_center()
        self.image_size = info.get_size()
        self.radius = info.get_radius()
        self.lifespan = info.get_lifespan()
        self.animated = info.get_animated()
        self.center_pos = [(self.pos[0] + self.image_width / 2), (self.pos[1] + self.image_height / 2)]
        self.age = 0
        if strip:
            self.strip = strip
            self.strip.iter()
        if sound:
            sound.stop()
            sound.play()

    def get_position(self):
        return self.pos


    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def collide(self, other_object):
        distance = dist(self.center_pos, other_object.center_pos)

        if distance > self.radius + other_object.get_radius():
            return False
        elif distance < self.radius + other_object.get_radius():
            return True

    def draw(self, tela):
        if self.animated:
            self.image = self.strip.next()
            tela.blit(self.image, self.pos)
        else:
            tela.blit(self.image, self.pos)

    def update(self):
        # Determinando a posicao
        self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]
        self.age += 1
        self.center_pos = [(self.pos[0] + self.image_width / 2), (self.pos[1] + self.image_height / 2)]

        # Envolvimento do ecra
        if self.pos[1] + self.image_height <= self.radius:
            self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] % Altura + self.image_height
        if self.pos[1] >= Altura:
            self.pos[1] = self.pos[1] % Altura - self.image_height

        if self.pos[0] + self.image_width <= 0:
            self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] % Largura + self.image_width
        if self.pos[0] >= Largura:
            self.pos[0] = self.pos[0] % Largura - self.image_width

        #Actualizacao do Angulo e da imagem
        self.angle += self.angle_vel
        self.image = rot_center(self.original, self.angle)

        # Verificando a vida util
        if self.age < self.lifespan:
            return False
        else:
            return True

# Verificar colisao
def group_collide(group, other_object):
    for elem in set(group):
        if elem.collide(other_object):
            an_explosion = Sprite(elem.get_position(), [0, 0], 0, 0, explosion_image, explosion_info, explosion_sound,
                                  explosion_sheet)
            explosion_group.add(an_explosion)
            group.remove(elem)
            return True
    else:
        return False

# Verificar colisao da bala com o asteroide
def group_group_collide(group1, group2):
    score_add = 0
    for elem in set(group1):
        if group_collide(group2, elem):
            group1.remove(elem)
            score_add += 5
    return score_add


def process_sprite_group(group, tela):
    for elem in set(group):
        elem.draw(tela)
        is_old = elem.update()
        if is_old:
            group.remove(elem)


def score_to_range():
    global pontos
    if pontos < 50:
        return 1
    elif pontos >= 50 and pontos < 100:
        return 2
    elif pontos >= 100:
        return 4
    else:
        return 5


# Manipulador do temporizador que gera uma rocha
def rock_spawner():
    global rock_group, iniciado, nave, pontos
    rang = score_to_range()
    if len(rock_group) < 5 and iniciado:
        vel = [0, 0]
        vel[0] = random.randrange(-(rang), rang + 1)
        vel[1] = random.randrange(-(rang), rang + 1)
        x = random.randrange(0, 800)
        y = random.randrange(0, 600)

        ang = (random.randrange(-5, 11))

        a_rock = Sprite([x, y], vel, 0, ang, asteroid_image, asteroid_info)
        distance = dist(nave.get_position(), a_rock.get_position())
        if distance > 100:
            rock_group.add(a_rock)


def restart():
    global rock_group, iniciado
    iniciado = False
    for elem in set(rock_group):
        rock_group.discard(elem)


def click(pos):
    global iniciado, vidas, pontos
    center = [Largura / 2, Altura / 2]
    size = splash_info.get_size()
    inwidth = (center[0] - size[0] / 2) < pos[0] < (center[0] + size[0] / 2)
    inheight = (center[1] - size[1] / 2) < pos[1] < (center[1] + size[1] / 2)
    vidas = 5
    pontos = 0
    if (not iniciado) and inwidth and inheight:
        soundtrack.stop()
        soundtrack.play()
        iniciado = True

#==============================================================================#
#                             Menu Principal                                   #
#==============================================================================#
def main():
    # Iniciar o pygame
    pygame.init()
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((Largura, Altura))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Rice Rocks')

    # Carregar os graficos
    ship_info = ImageInfo([45, 45], [90, 90], 35)
    ship_sheet = spritesheet.spritesheet('art/double_ship.png')
    ship_images = ship_sheet.images_at(((0, 0, 90, 90), (90, 0, 90, 90)), colorkey=(255, 255, 255))

    global explosion_info
    explosion_info = ImageInfo([64, 64], [128, 128], 17, 24, True)
    global explosion_image, explosion_sheet
    explosion_sheet = SpriteStripAnim('art/explosion_alpha.png', (0, 0, 128, 128), 24, (255, 255, 255), True, 2)
    explosion_sheet.iter()
    explosion_image = explosion_sheet.next()

    global splash_info
    splash_info = ImageInfo([200, 150], [400, 300])
    global splash_image
    splash_image = carregar_imagem('splash.png')

    global asteroid_info
    asteroid_info = ImageInfo([45, 45], [90, 90], 40)
    global asteroid_image
    asteroid_image = carregar_imagem('asteroid_blue.png')

    global missile_info
    missile_info = ImageInfo([5, 5], [10, 10], 3, 50)
    global missile_image
    missile_image = carregar_imagem('shot2.png')

    # Caregar os sons
    global ship_thrust_sound, missile_sound, explosion_sound, soundtrack
    soundtrack = carregar_som('music.ogg')
    soundtrack.set_volume(0.5)
    missile_sound = carregar_som('shoot.wav')
    ship_thrust_sound = carregar_som('thrust.wav')
    ship_thrust_sound.set_volume(0.05)
    explosion_sound = carregar_som('explode.wav')
    explosion_sound.set_volume(0.05)

    # Inicializar a nave e outros objectos
    global nave
    nave = Nave([Largura / 2, Altura / 2], [0, 0], 0, ship_images, ship_info)
    global rock_group, missile_group, explosion_group
    explosion_group = set([])
    rock_group = set([])
    missile_group = set([])

    # Carregar o background
    debris_info = ImageInfo([320, 240], [640, 480])
    background = carregar_imagem('nebula_blue.f2014.png')
    debris_image = carregar_imagem('debris2_blue.png')

    # Inicializar a fonte e cores dos objectos, utilizando a fonte predefinida do pygame
    fontObj = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
    white_color = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)

    # Inicializar os objectos do jogo
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 1000)

    # Ciclo do jogo
    while 1:
        clock.tick(60)
        # Event listener
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == QUIT:
                return
            if evento.type == USEREVENT + 1:
                rock_spawner()

            # Registar os controles do jogo
            if evento.type == KEYDOWN and evento.key == K_RIGHT:
                nave.turn(-5)
            if evento.type == KEYDOWN and evento.key == K_LEFT:
                nave.turn(5)
            if evento.type == KEYDOWN and evento.key == K_UP:
                nave.move(True)
            if evento.type == KEYUP and evento.key == K_UP:
                nave.move(False)
            if evento.type == KEYUP and evento.key == K_RIGHT:
                nave.turn(0)
            if evento.type == KEYUP and evento.key == K_LEFT:
                nave.turn(0)
            if evento.type == KEYUP and evento.key == K_ESCAPE:
                return
            if evento.type == KEYUP and evento.key == K_SPACE:
                nave.shoot()
            if evento.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                click(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

        # Registar os controles do jogo
        nave.update()

        # Verificar colisoes com a nave
        global pontos, vidas
        if group_collide(rock_group, nave):
            vidas -= 1
        pontos += group_group_collide(missile_group, rock_group)

        # Desenhar tudo
        # Desenhar e animar o fundo
        global tempo
        tempo += 1
        wtime = (tempo / 4) % Largura
        tela.blit(background, (0, 0))
        tela.blit(debris_image, ((wtime - Largura / 2) - 320, (Altura / 2) - 240))
        tela.blit(debris_image, ((wtime + Largura / 2) - 320, (Altura / 2) - 240))

        nave.draw(tela)
        process_sprite_group(missile_group, tela)
        process_sprite_group(explosion_group, tela)
        process_sprite_group(rock_group, tela)

        # Desenhar os pontos e as vidas na camada mais externa
        tela.blit(fontObj.render("Pontos: %d" % pontos, True, white_color), (0, 0))
        tela.blit(fontObj.render("Vidas: %d" % vidas, True, white_color), (620, 0))

        # Desenhar a tela inicial se o jogo nao estiver funcionando
        if not iniciado:
            tela.blit(splash_image,
                        (Largura / 2 - (splash_info.get_size()[0] / 2), Altura / 2 - (splash_info.get_size()[1] / 2)))

        pygame.display.flip()
        if vidas == 0:
            restart()


print("Se voce esta, vendo isso, e porque o pygame foi importado com sucesso")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()][1]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook

Comment: @Carlos do you have two versions of python installed?

Comment: Yes Anthony i have python 3.4 and 2.7.

Comment: @clockwatcher i tried to use that code but it's for python 2.7. i'm using python 3.4

Comment: @CarlosFrederico It is possible pygame was installed for python 27

Answer (score 0):

Following error:

> "Import error, no module named pygame"

occurs because you're not installed (or installed incorrectly) pygame module.

If you're using Python 3.3, then you should use pygame 3.3. MSI installer available at [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads).

Comment: I installed a new pygame but it stills giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use python 2.7 and pygame for python 2.7. Also look at the documentation for pygame2exe instead of normal py2exe. It worked better for me. `http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook`

Comment: Make sure the setup.py file is written in a 2.7 IDE. Just incase, dunno if that would be an issue.

Comment: I wrote that code in python 3.4 and i will present this work tomorrow.